# Carrierwave: Duplicating File In a Second Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have two models, each with their own Carrierwave uploaders:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

and:

```
class Bookshelf < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

I want the user's avatar to be the latest bookshelf image he's uploaded. I try to achieve this like so:

```
class BookcasesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @bookcase = current_user.bookcases.build(params[:bookcase])
    if @bookcase.save
      current_user.avatar = @bookcase.image
      current_user.avatar.recreate_versions!
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, this has no effect on the avatar at all. How else might I achieve this?

Comment: Shot in the dark -- have you tried adding `current_user.avatar.save` ?

Comment: Close. I needed `current_user.update_attribute(:avatar, @bookcase.image)`. If you want to put that in an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
current_user.avatar = @bookcase.image
current_user.avatar.recreate_versions!
```

Doesn't actually save --- you can either:

```
current_user.avatar.save
```

or as you put:

```
current_user.update_attribute(:avatar, @bookcase.image)
```

Comment: Hi @JesseWolgamott, this work perfectly when you try to copy an image the first time, if you try to copy it again for the second time, it won't create the folder with the expected second copied image, do you know why ?

Comment: @medBo -- no, not without code. You should open a question referencing this one.

Comment: i have already posted this question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869646/why-carrierwave-image-is-not-duplicated-the-second-time

Comment: When copying remote files (eg. S3) between models, check out `remote_*_url`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361702/carrierwave-creating-a-duplicate-attachment-when-duplicating-its-containing-mod

Comment: @JesseWolgamott `current_user.avatar.save` doesn't work, uploader doesn't have a `save` method

Comment: Thank you!
`current_user.update_attribute(:avatar, @bookcase.image)` works for me as well as `current_user.avatar = @bookcase.image`

Answer (score 1):

If your image file is stored locally and you don't mind opening a file descriptor, you could also do this:

```
current_user.avatar = File.open(@bookcase.image.path)
current_user.save
```