# Why CarrierWave image is not duplicated the second time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I try to duplicate a record many time using this code :

```
my_obj = Obj.find_by(id: params[:id])
new_obj = my_obj.dup
```

I use CarrierWave to mount an image to my Obj

```
class Obj < ActiveRecord::Base
   mount_uploader :image, ObjImageUploader
end
```

my first code above, duplicate the obj as well but it doesn't duplicate the image correctly, it shows instead something like `Medium 2013 08 04 14354`, so i tried to fix this using

```
new_obj = my_obj.dup
new_obj.image = my_obj.image
```

and now it works correctly, the image is shown as well

if i try to duplicate the duplicated new_obj itself

```
another_obj = new_obj.dup
another_obj.image = new_obj.image
```

it shows me again `Medium 2013 08 04 14354...`

so **i get this if i copy a copied image, then when i search for the created folder with image there is no folder/image created**

What's going wrong here ?

Comment: when you duplicate the object do you create a new id?

Comment: i do new_obj.save which create the id for me